# display the total sum of a typed item in an observable array collection

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, mvvm, knockout.js

please i need help on how to display the total sum of a typed item in an  observable array. whenever i try, the returned result is always NaN. Below is the sample. MyVM.js file:

```
//Model
var Course = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.title = ko.observable(data.Title);
    self.creditHour = ko.observable(data.CreditHour);
self.result = ko.observableArray(data.result);
    return self;
}
//View Model
var CourseList = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.courses = ko.observableArray([]);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Student/Register_For_Courses',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: 'json',
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(data, function (data) {
                self.courses.push(new Course(data))          
            });

        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err.status + " : " + err.statusText);
        }

    });

    self.tHour = ko.pureComputed(function () {
    var total = 0;
    var count=self.courses().length;
    for (var i = 0; i <count ;i++)
    {
        var course =  Course(self.courses()[i]);
        total += parseInt(course.creditHour(),10);
    }
    return total;
});
    // button functions
    self.removeCourse = function (course) { self.courses.remove(course); }


}

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new CourseList());
});
```

Here is my View

```
<tr>
   Total CH<td data-bind="text:tHour"></td>
</tr>
```

The returned value is NaN.

Comment: can you show a sample of your data you're getting from Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this. https://jsfiddle.net/othkss9s/19/

I used the knockout utility arrayForEach to add them up http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html

I couldn't do your ajax call so I just hardcoded Data but it should represent what you get back from your ajax call.  here is the code.

```
var Data = [{
  title: "English",
  creditHour: 3.23,
  result: "A"
}, {
  title: "Gym",
  creditHour: 1.04,
  result: "A"
}, {
  title: "AP Calc",
  creditHour: 4.34,
  result: "B"
}, ]

function course(data) {
  this.title = ko.observable(data.title);
  this.creditHour = ko.observable(data.creditHour);
  this.result = ko.observable(data.result);
}

function model() {
  var self = this;
  this.courses = ko.observableArray("");
  this.totalCreditHours = ko.computed(function() {
    var total = 0;
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.courses(), function(item) {
      var value = parseFloat(item.creditHour());
      if (!isNaN(value)) {
        total += value;
      }
    });
    return total.toFixed(2);
  }, this);
};

var myViewModel = new model();

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
  $.each(Data, function(idx, obj) {
    myViewModel.courses.push(
      new course(obj)
    );
  });

});
```